# Can I show, hide and toggle results in PHP echo?

Tags: php, html

Basically by clicking the "comment" link the last result of the query should show and by clicking again it should be hidden. I have tried Rocket's code as well but I get an error message in the bottom of the browser and when I click "comments" it just takes me to the top of the page. I would apprieciate some advice on this

```
$i = 1; // ID Counter 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{    
echo "<h1>$row[title]</h1>";    
echo "<p class ='second'>$row[blog_content]</p> ";     
echo "<p class='meta'>Posted by .... &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; $row[date] &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; <a href='#' onclick=\"toggle_visibility('something$i');\">Comments</a><div id='something$i'   style='display: none;'>$row[comment]</div>";    
$i++; // Increment counter 
}
```

Comment: Are the `*` part of your code?  You can't make text bold or italic inside of a code block.

Comment: escape the quotes with backslashes `\"something2\"`

Comment: I don't know what's *, but you should escape the quoetes, onclick=\"toggle_visibility('something2');\"

Comment: well I thought * is what you use on this site to show specific parts of code. sorry that was dumb of me

Comment: @ozzysmith `*` doesnt work inside of `<code>` blocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a loop, echoing the same thing over and over, thus making all the `div`s have the same ID, `something2`.

IDs need to be unique, you gonna have to make unique IDs for each div.

Something like: `<div id='something$i' style='display: none;'>` (remembering to increment `$i`).

Also, you're gonna to escape the quotes in your `onclick` attribute.

```
<a href='#' onclick=\"toggle_visibility('something$i');\">
```

The code should look something like this:

```
$i = 1; // ID Counter
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "<h1>$row[title]</h1>";
   echo "<p class ='second'>$row[blog_content]</p> "; 
   echo "<p class='meta'>Posted by .... &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; $row[date] &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; <a href='#' onclick=\"toggle_visibility('something$i');\">Comments</a><div id='something$i' style='display: none;'>$row[comment]</div>";
   $i++; // Increment counter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quotes :

```
$blah = "onclick='toggle_visibility(\"something2\");'>Comments</a>"
```

There is an easier way to hiding / showing the next sibling ....

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle(this,event)">try this</a>
<div style="display:none">some hidden content</div>​

function toggle(el,ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();  // prevent the link from being followed
    el = next(el);        // get the next element
    if (el.style.display == "none") { // toggle the display
        el.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        el.style.display = "none";
    }
}
/* 
   Credit to John Resig for this function 
   taken from Pro JavaScript techniques 
*/
function next(elem) {
    do {
        elem = elem.nextSibling;
    } while (elem && elem.nodeType != 1);
    return elem;                
}
​
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fUZKU/)

Answer (score 0):

You can throw in a counter into your code as the while loop is executing to dynamically generate unique id's for each comment div. Or, you can pull a unique field out of the query result for the id's, as long as you hook up to it appropriately later if it ends up being used and remain consistent in the rest of the code.

either

```
$count = count($result);
...
while (...){
  $count--;
  echo '... id="something'. $count .'" ...'
}
```

or...

```
while (...){
  echo '... id="something'. $row['ID'] .'" ...'
}
```

Comment: Of course, using javascript is easier, better, more powerful and more responsive. You may not have the confidence to tackle that right away, so choose what you can manage and learn now or later.